# Blocking user using privacy list in ejabberd returns "not-well-formed"

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I want to block other user in ejabberd on basis of jid. I am trying to send iq stanza through `send_stanza_c2s` command. Like :-

```
send_stanza_c2s admin localhost Smack "<iq from='admin@localhost/Smack' type='set' id='msg1'><query xmlns="jabber:iq:privacy"><list name="blocked"><item type="jid" value="jack10@localhost" action="deny" order="3"/><message/></item></list></query></iq>"
```

But it is giving me error.

```
Error: {4,<<"not well-formed (invalid token)">>}
```

Please help me with this.

Also guide me on if blocking user is achievable only through privacy lists (XEP-0016).

Answer (score 1):

The IQ request stanza you send to the server is not well formed, I.e. invalid. If you used [Smack's API for privacy lists](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.7/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/privacy/PrivacyListManager.html) then you should report this as bug.